# what is volume 'type' error in docker-compos

Tags: docker-compose

im new in docker and docker-compos.
this is my Docker and its created successfully.

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
COPY . .
ARG name
RUN apt-get update
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  django_web:
    build: .
    command: >
      apt -c "python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && gunicorn mlAmeri.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - static: /app/staitc
      - media: /app/media
      - .: /app

    ports:
      - 8010:8000

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
      - ./nginx/config/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - django_web


volumes:
#  postgres_data:
  static:
  media:
```

and this my error

> services.django_web.volumes 'type' is a required property

what's meaning of type ? what i miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing some quotes I believe:

```yaml
volumes:
  - "static:/app/staitc"
  - "media:/app/media"
  - ".:/app"
```

See the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes

Edit: note that it's not a good practice to mount the entire current folder into the container though. You will be leaking unnecessary stuff in the container.